# Postgres revoke database access from user

Tags: postgresql

When I tried

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres from admin;
```

but the user `admin` is still able to connect to `postgres` remotely via `pgadmin` after that.

How do I completely revoke an user's access to a database?

Log: https://pastebin.com/raw/Q2mfkf3P

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The right to connect is by default granted to `PUBLIC`.  You would have to revoke it from `PUBLIC` (and then grant it individually to other users who need it) to accomplish what you want.

Or use `pg_hba.conf` to deny the connection.

Comment: Do I run `revoke all on schema public from public`? Both this and editing `pg_hba.conf` still allow `admin` to see the existence of the database. Is there a way to hide the database from the user completely?

Comment: @Avery235 `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb FROM public;`

Answer (score 0):

I think his session is still running.
The simple way to see it is:
`\conninfo`

Take a look at this, to avoid to restart postgresql:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection#answer-5109190

EDIT

Hoping that this [link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Shared_Database_Hosting) will be usefull.

Comment: I want to hide the database from the user completely. That solution still allows user to see the existence of that database.